# How indent a bullet list in NovaCode-DocX using C#

Tags: c#, novacode-docx

How indent a bullet list in novocode DocX using C#

I used IndentationFirstLine property but it is not working properly.

I need to indent a bullet list in Novacode-DocX using C#.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I had found it myself. Loop through the generated list like:

```
foreach (Paragraph pItem in list.Items)
{
    pItem.IndentationBefore = int.Parse(IndentLeftValue);                                                                 
}
```

The list items are actually paragraphs to which you can set indent